# Возврат страницы в нужное положение

Tags: php, javascript

Такая ситуация: есть простой интернет магазин, реализованный только средствами PHP. При выборе товаров, предположим в середине страницы, переходим в сам товар, после, при нажатии "назад" страница возвращается к началу в самый вверх, что очень неудобно. Как можно сделать так, чтобы после возвращения страница автоматически возвращалась в то место, где была нажата кнопка?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно использовать "якорь", добавьте элементу, на который вы хотите позиционировать страницу атрибут name. Например (это не обязательно должна быть ссылка, можно использовать другой тэг)

```
<a name='middle'></a>
```

После этого, добавьте в конц URL последовательность #middle

```
http://example.com/form/edit/34324#middle
```

Браузер позиционирует страницу на элемент с таким атрибутом name.